# How to use awk to print lines where a field matches a specific string?

Tags: sed, awk

I have:

```
1 LINUX param1 value1 
2 LINUXparam2 value2
3 SOLARIS param3 value3
4 SOLARIS param4 value4
```

I need awk to print all lines in which `$2` is `LINUX`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

In `awk`:

```
awk '$2 == "LINUX" { print $0 }' test.txt
```

See [`awk` by Example](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-awk1/) for a good intro to `awk`.

In `sed`:

```
sed -n -e '/^[0-9][0-9]* LINUX/p' test.txt
```

See [`sed` by Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20170314221201/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-sed1/index.html/) for a good intro to `sed`.

Comment: what about LINUX can be linux or Linux ?

Comment: The pages I linked to explain about how to use regexes in the respective tools. The regex to match LINUX or Linux is L(INUX|inux) (roughly speaking; different tools sometimes have slightly different syntax). BTW, if this is homework, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: If you want the match to be completely case insensitive, check out the `toupper` (or `tolower`) functions in `awk`.

Comment: Note that the default action already is `print $0`, so this is all that's required: `awk 'toupper($2)=="LINUX"' test.txt`

Comment: @HankGay "awk by Example" URL is not valid anymore.

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan `Awk by example` now lives at https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-awk1/

Answer (score 26):

This is a case in which you can use the beautiful idiomatic `awk`:

```
awk '$2=="LINUX"' file
```

That is:

- The default action of `awk` when in a True condition is to print the current line.
- Since `$2 == "LINUX"` is true whenever the 2nd field is LINUX, this will print those lines in which this happens.

---

In case you want to print all those lines matching `LINUX` no matter if it is upper or lowercase, use [`toupper()`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) to capitalize them all:

```
awk 'toupper($2)=="LINUX"' file
```

Or `IGNORECASE` with either of these syntaxs:

```
awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1} $2=="LINUX"' file
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '$2=="LINUX"' file
```

Answer (score 17):

My answer is very late, but no one has mentioned:

```
awk '$2~/LINUX/' file
```

Comment: I like this one, because is matches partial strings, ie it would still match LINUX_OS for example

Comment: sorry for necroing but far more versatile solution than others

Comment: If you need a regular expression - yes, upvoted for this. But if you need exact match, others make more sense.

Comment: @akostadinov: For an exact match use: *awk '$2~/^LINUX$/' file*

Comment: @enegue, why should I use a regex for an exact match? Moreover if I want to match special characters the regex will go even more in the way. Don't try to use a hammer instead of a screwdriver or vise versa.

Comment: Regex is just an alternative tool, that is, in the case of the OP, quite simple to implement -- as you can see. BTW, thank you for your upvote.

Answer (score 6):

Try these out:

```
egrep -i '^\w+ LINUX ' myfile

awk '{IGNORECASE=1}{if ($2 == "LINUX") print}' myfile

sed -ne '/^[0-9]* [Ll][Ii][Nn][Uu][Xx] /p' myfile
```

edit: modified for case insensitivity

Comment: The question explicitly mentions `awk` (and `sed` in a comment).

Comment: what about LINUX can be linux or Linux ?

Answer (score 5):

I think it might be a good idea to include "exact" and "partial matching" cases using `awk` ))

So, for **exact matching**:

```sh
OTHER_SHELL_COMMAND | awk '$2 == "LINUX" { print $0 }'
```

And for **partial matching**:

```sh
OTHER_SHELL_COMMAND | awk '$2 ~ /LINUX/ { print $0 }'
```

Answer (score 4):

In GNU `sed` case-insensitive matches can be made using the `I` modifier:

```
sed -n '/^[^[:space:]][[:space:]]\+linux[[:space:]]\+/Ip'
```

Will robustly match "linux", "Linux", "LINUX", "LiNuX" and others as the second field (after the first field which may be *any* non-whitespace character) and surrounded by any amount (at least one) of any whitespace (primarily space and tab, although you can use `[:blank:]` to limit it to strictly those).