# finding real life names and csh login shell

Tags: csh

When I awk the etc/passwd file for real life names how do I single out the csh shell logins:

```
awk -F":" ' {print $5} /etc/passwd
```

I need to find the users that have the csh login shell

Comment: On some systems, `/etc/passwd` doesn't contain the full list of user accounts; account information can also be stored in NIS, LDAP, or other sources. `getent passwd` should know about these other sources.

Answer (score 0):

```
/bin/sh
cat /etc/passwd | grep -w csh | while read line
do
  user=`echo $line | awk -F: '{print $1}'`
  echo User $user is using csh
done
```

Or to do this on one line, without grep, as requested (also see this answer for more examples: [Only print lines where the second field matches some criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957094/awk-and-or-sed-only-print-lines-where-the-second-field-matches-some-criteria))

But the short version is:

```
awk -F: '$7 == "/bin/csh" {print $5}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Can I do this with the command I provided without using grep?