# grep an element in a df and display only selected columns with bash

Tags: bash, dataframe, grep

Hel lo I have a df file such as

```
col1;col2;col3;col4
A;B;C;D
E;F;G;H
I;J;K;L
```

and I would like to `grep I` and only `display the col1 and col2`

and get

```
I;J then
```

because from now I only know how to do :

```
grep 'I' df.csv 

    I;J;K;L
```

Comment: I can't find an exact duplicate, but there has to be one... this is a problem well suited for awk.

Comment: This is very close, but goes the other way (match field and print whole line): https://stackoverflow.com/q/2957094/3266847

Comment: Does it mean you want to `grep` for all lines where `I` is present in column1 or column2?

Comment: @Freddy it means That I want to print col1 and col2 only for lines where I is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep 'I' df.csv | cut -d';' -f1-2
```

The `cut` command will treat each input line as a list of fields separated by `;` (`-d';'`), and will select only the first two fields (`-f1-2`) for output.

---

Sample session:

```
$ cat df.csv 
col1;col2;col3;col4
A;B;C;D
E;F;G;H
I;J;K;L
$ grep 'I' df.csv | cut -d';' -f1-2
I;J
$
```

Comment: and what if I want only column1 and 3 ? and not the 2

Comment: @Grendel To get columns 1 and 3, use `-f1,3` instead of `-f1-2`.  See `man cut` for details.